# Laravel 4 service provider instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying do to facade with laravel 4. I am using service provider. In the service provider register I make singleton instance but I want to access it through interface. It is working I just do not know how to access the interface with the reference to that object. My code is bellow:

```
class AuthenticationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
         \App::singleton('Auth\iAuthenticate', function()
         {
            return new DbAuthentication();
         });            
    }

}
```

And then if I write this in another php class:

```
Auth\iAuthenticate::someMethod()
```

It returns that I cannot call abstract methods which doesn't supprise me. How can I access instance that was created within service provider?

Comment: Have you tried `$instance = App::make('Auth\iAuthenticate');`?

Comment: Not really... That is actualy the answer. :)

Comment: Okay, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$instance = App::make('Auth\iAuthenticate');`

It's also suggested to use the `this->app` property.  It might save you from some headaches in the future.

```
public function register()
{
     $this->app->singleton('Auth\iAuthenticate', function()
     {
        return new DbAuthentication();
     });            
}
```